# Can you link a MD file to you repository's wiki?

Tags: github

So I'm using an npm package called [jsdoc-to-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-to-markdown) to generate my documentation files, and I want to link them to that same repo's wiki. So how would I do that??

[my repo](https://github.com/ErrorBot1122/Roblox-File-Handler/tree/unstable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GitHub, your wiki's git repository is stored at "https://github.com/org/repo.wiki.git". You'll want to copy your files to there and then push to it.

EDIT: For you, that would be https://github.com/ErrorBot1122/Roblox-File-Handler.wiki.git.

Comment: how would i do that with VSCode / Gitpod

Comment: also it is giving me 404 error, and what about branches

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND You need to `git clone` the repository, not click the link. Then `git checkout` to the branch you want.

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND Update: It appears you do not have Wiki enabled. You can't clone the repository before you do that. And as I said previously, do not use the link, use `git clone` and `git checkout`.

Comment: how would i add the branch to the end? also it keeps saying:
`Your branch is up to date with 'origin/unstable'.`

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND In the settings tab of your repository, scroll down to the "features" header and click the "Wikis" checkbox. Once you have done that, open your terminal (Command Prompt on Windows, Terminal on macOS, and usually Terminal on Linux but it depends), and type `git clone https://github.com/ErrorBot1122/Roblox-File-Handler.wiki.git`. Then, type `cd Roblox-File-Handler`. Finally, type `git checkout unstable`. Once you've done that, run `jsdoc-to-markdown`.